# How to prioritize a particular process on start up?

Tags: process, linux-kernel

In Linux, I want a process to be assigned with higher priority than usual. I.e. when a process starts I want it's priority to be set to higher value. I want this to be done implicitly, i.e when the process starts (eg.:on a double click).

For this will I have to change the kernel code (sched.c)?

And are there any tools or packages using which I can see how exactly a process starts and how the priorities are assigned?

Would **ptrace** ( http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) and **strace** ( http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) help me with this?

Comment: I think your title and tag are somewhat misleading. You don't really want to change the scheduler's kernel code, do you? I think you just want to run something at process startup, which would change its priority.

Comment: i want to initialize KVM process's priority on it's startup.. I don't want to make use of renice (or any such command) after the process has started.. can that be done without changing kernel code?? Was thinking of making changes in sched_fork() function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the process call the set_priority() system call in main() to lower it's nice level and raise it's priority. See the man page for details: http://linux.die.net/man/2/setpriority

You can also mark the process as a real time process using sched_setscheduler() but that is a little bit more involved and probably an overkill for what you seek.

You 100% don't need to change the kernel for this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to hack the actual application itself you can always create a custom desktop file which wraps the command with "nice" which will modify the niceness (priority) of the command you'll run.

For example, create a ~/.local/share/applications/myfastapp.desktop which looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=nice -n -20 /usr/bin/myapp
Name=My App (niced)
Comment=Custom definition for myapp
```

Comment: Thanks.. :) The answer is quite high level for me.. Kindly do provide the references to understand the above solution..

Comment: .desktop files are simply a window manager agnostic way of describing applications. See http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ for a description of their format. For example gnome shell only presents applications to the use that have a defined .desktop file (either from the package or a user defined one).